# Use Mango to search MongoDB by multiple ObjectIDs

Tags: perl, mongodb

How can I find multiple MongoDB documents by their ObjectIDs using Mango in one go. I currently have a non-blocking sub which I'm using to filter out the docs that don't match in a grep statement but was wondering if it's possible to pass the ObjectIDs (maybe an array of instances of Mango::BSON::ObjectID) to the find method?
I also think it's not very efficient this way since big collections will bare a hefty price!

```
@items;
$self->mango->db->collection('items')->find()->all(sub {
    my ($collection, $err, $items) = @_;
    return $self->render_exception($err) if $err;

    my @oids = $self->req->params->param('ids[]');

    foreach my $item (@$items) {
        push @items, $item if grep (/$item->{_id}/, @oids);
    }

    $self->render(json => {items => \@items});
});
```

This sub is inside one of my Mojolicous controllers which responds to a JSON call.
I'm using the following:

- Mojolicous 4.91
- Mango 0.24
- MongoDB 2.4.9

Thanks in advance.

**Update**

I have applied Neil's logic and now it works fine.

```
my @oids = map { Mango::BSON::ObjectID->new($_) } ($self->req->params->param('ids[]'));
print Dumper(@oids),"\n";

$self->mango->db->collection('items')->find({ "_id" => {'$in' => \@oids} })->all(sub {
    my ($collection, $err, $items) = @_;
    return $self->render_exception($err) if $err;

    print Dumper($items),"\n";

    $self->render(json => {items => $items});
});
```

The dumped OIDs are as follows:

```
$VAR1 = bless( {
             'oid' => '52faf6de10d041d196cb545b'
           }, 'Mango::BSON::ObjectID' );
$VAR2 = bless( {
             'oid' => '5300409310d041d196cb545d'
           }, 'Mango::BSON::ObjectID' );
```

and the found objects will look something like this (depending on your structure):

```
$VAR1 = [
      {
        '_id' => bless( {
                          'oid' => '52faf6de10d041d196cb545b'
                        }, 'Mango::BSON::ObjectID' ),
        'class' => [
                     'Sport'
                   ],
        'make' => '4321',
        'year' => 2012
      },
      {
        '_id' => bless( {
                          'oid' => '5300409310d041d196cb545d'
                        }, 'Mango::BSON::ObjectID' ),
        'class' => [
                     'Classic'
                   ],
        'make' => '1234',
        'year' => 2014
      }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be looking for the [**`$in`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator. So rather than looping all the items to find the ones that match you pass in the `_id` values sent to your controller within the call to `find()`:

```
my @oids = $self->req->params->param('ids[]');

$self->mango->db->collection('items')
    ->find({ "_id" => { '$in' => \@oids }  })->all(sub {
    my ($collection, $err, $items) = @_;
    return $self->render_exception($err) if $err;

    $self->render(json => {items => $items});
});
```

---

### Update

Actually had some time to test this with Mango and managed to get a working case:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5345faf8a1f97e61848485e8"), "prerequisites" : [ "a" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5345fafea1f97e61848485e9"), "prerequisites" : [ "a", "b" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5345fb02a1f97e61848485ea"), "prerequisites" : [ "a", "c" ] }
```

And then running with the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use Modern::Perl;

use EV;
use AnyEvent;
use Data::Dumper;
use Mango;
use Mango::BSON::ObjectID;

my $mango = Mango->new();

my $cv = AE::cv;

my $col  = $mango->db('test')->collection('courses');

my @oids = (
  "5345fafea1f97e61848485e9",
  "5345fb02a1f97e61848485ea"
);

@oids = map { Mango::BSON::ObjectID->new($_) } @oids;


$col->find({ '_id' => { '$in' => \@oids } })->all( sub {
  my ( $cursor, $err, $docs ) = @_;

  $cv->send( Dumper( $docs ) );

});


say $cv->recv;
```

So that actually will select the correct documents from the sample, and it does seem that the ObjectID values need to be passed in that way in order to match.

At least there should be enough there to debug from.

Comment: Thanks for your post Neil, I did try using the `$in` operator but wasn't too sure of the way I'm passing it into the `find` method. Anyway, I tried your variant and tried `find({ _id => {'$in' => \@oids} })` too but to no avail, I get an empty set (array) reference of documents!

Comment: @Ashraf a very silly typing mistake is at fault here since I never added which field to match to the $in operator. See the edited code.

Comment: Hmm, I still get an empty set with `find({ "_id" => {'$in' => \@oids} })` ... wrapping the `_id` key with double quotes was the only difference but I don't think it would have mattered. Mind you, I even mapped the `@oids` into an array of `Mango::BSON::ObjectID` objects with `my @oids = map { Mango::BSON::ObjectID->new($_) } ($self->req->params->param('ids[]'))` but that doesn't help either.

Comment: @Ashraf actually I totally omitted the `_id` key previously. Try dumping the "req->params" to make sure you are getting what you need. But I basically do not understand how your code example can work but the listing does not. They should basically be the same except for the use of $in. MongoDB should not care less whether this is a ObejctId type or a string. In fact the driver should actually stringify this.

Comment: Absolutely, I was actually referring to my previous comment on the `_id` key after you have modified the answer. I do actually dump the `@oids` to check and it does seem rather clean; 24 alphanumeric array of strings, I also dump the $items object inside `find` to check the returned value, that's how I can tell it's empty. I think the code works because the driver is not generating any errors but maybe a bug causing it to silently fail? I'll check the driver's code.

Comment: @Ashraf can you possibly add that information to your question. I am actually meaning to bump sebastian on a few things given the recent 2.6 release of mongo.

Comment: @Ashraf Traced down a working case that should give you enough to go on for debugging

Comment: Apologies, Neil ... I've upgraded to Mango 0.30 and MongoDB 2.6.0 and it's no longer giving me an empty array (although it causes other issue :S ). I decided to roll them back to 0.24 and 2.4.9, respectively, and test again but I can't reproduce anymore. I honestly think I might have had a silly typo in my sample data! In any case, I wanted to thank you so much for your help. I'll update my post with my dump data and accept your answer shortly. Again, thanks ever so much for your help.